# How do players/browsers handle DISCONTINUITY tags in HLS?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming, http-live-streaming, audio-streaming

How do browsers and video players handle DISCONTINUITY tags in HLS? Do browsers/players do reset or flush buffers or timecodes when they encounter this tag? How does this tag affect video and audio streams in HLS segments?

Comment: I think many players have added this functionality recently, often driven by server side ad insertion use cases. Probably the best way to see what players do is to look at some of the open source ones - for example Shaka Player added support for this in this update which is publicly available: https://github.com/shaka-project/shaka-player/commit/734d129fcdefcfca777bdbc394f3cc96c7893b13